# How to prevent form submission without reCaptcha verification in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I'm using Google reCaptcha v2 on my rails app to verify submission of a form but I can't figure out how to link reCaptcha verification and form submission, no matter whether the reCaptcha is checked or not the form always submits.

I'm using the `recaptcha` gem as well and have set everything up according to the documentation and it appears as though the verification itself works, it just isn't tied to form submission.

Here is the relevant code:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@video, @video.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%# Other tags %>
  <%= recaptcha_tags %>
<% end %>
```

**comments_controller.html.erb**

```
def create
    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
    @comment = @video.comments.create(comment_params)
    if verify_recaptcha!(model: @comment) && @comment.save
        redirect_to @video
    else
        # I had "render 'new'" here as the documentation did but that caused an error
    end
end
```

**config/initializers/recaptcha.rb**

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.site_key  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  config.secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
end
```

**Error generated by `render "new"`**

```
Missing template comments/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :arb, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: *...
```

The error just appears to be because there isn't anything set for comments/new but I'm not sure how to add that.

Comment: you may already know but worth the warning : don't put sensitive data in your post :)

Comment: "I had "render 'new'" here as the documentation did but that caused en error" can you show us the error ?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Please show the relevant route.

Comment: How can I find that?

Comment: In the `config/routes.rb` file. I'm looking to see what "new" you're trying to render. The missing template error means that you have `def new` in your controller but you don't have a view under `comments/new`.

Comment: What is the view users are currently going to in order to post a comment?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what the code is trying to accomplish with `render "new"` because that is the part that executes if validation isn't passed, what would need to be rendered if validation wasn't passed? As far as the view goes the user would be looking at the `video/index` or `video/show` views in which are rendered partials for the `comments/_form` and `comments/_comment` views.

Comment: You might want to make this into a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `.create` when you initialize `@comment`. `.create` makes a new object and saves it in one step, so you're saving it before you verify recaptcha. Use `@comment = @video.comments.new(comment_params)`.

Comment: Awesome, that did it for stopping the form from submitting without validation, now I just need it to do something when not validated since `render 'new'` as in the documentation generates an error which I'm editing into the question.